# Meteor Method: I keep getting a insert failed:Access Denied error on the Console

Tags: meteor, methods, access-denied

I cant figure out why I am getting this error. I have created a Meteor Method. Maybe I just need a second set of eyes and point out my mistake. Im creating a Instant Messaging App, where online users can have one on one chats. As soon as I click on the online user(routing). The console instantly has an

> insert failed:access denied.

If I attempt to send a message, This is the error I get.

> j…y.Event {originalEvent: Event, type: "submit", timeStamp:
>   1455207989065, jQuery1112075371492956765: true, which: undefined…}
>   meteor.js:862 insert failed: Access denied meteor.js:862 update
>   failed: Access denied 17799meteor.js:862 insert failed: Access denied

Im really new to Meteor and any help or advice would be very much appreciated.

Here is my HTML

```
    <template name="chat_page">
    <h2>Type in the box below to send a message!</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="well well-lg">
            {{#each messages}}
            {{> chat_message}}
            {{/each}}
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form class="js-send-chat">
            <input class="input" type="text" name="chat" placeholder="type a message here...">
            <button class="btn btn-default">send</button>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<!-- simple template that displays a message -->
<template name="chat_message">
    <div class = "container">
        <div class = "row">
            <img src="/{{profile.avatar}}" class="avatar_img">
            {{username}} said: {{text}}
        </div>
    </div>  
    <br>
</template>
```

Client Side

```
Template.chat_page.helpers({
    messages:function(){
      var chat = Chats.findOne({_id:Session.get("chatId")});
      return chat.messages;
    }, 
    other_user:function(){
      return ""
    }, 

  });

 Template.chat_page.events({
  'submit .js-send-chat':function(event){
    console.log(event);
    event.preventDefault();
    var chat = Chats.findOne({_id:Session.get("chatId")});
    if (chat){
      var msgs = chat.messages; 
      if (!msgs){
        msgs = [];
      }
      msgs.push({text: event.target.chat.value});
      event.target.chat.value = "";
      chat.messages = msgs;
      Chats.update(chat._id, chat);
      Meteor.call("sendMessage", chat);
    }
  }
 })
```

Method

```
Meteor.methods({
  sendMessage: function (chat) {
    Chats.insert({
      chat: chat,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      username: Meteor.user().profile.username,
      avatar: Meteor.user().profile.avatar,
    });
  },
});
```

Comment: if only you had gone through a good starting documentation!! check this our http://meteortips.com/book.pdf

Comment: Hey, Thanks. This will help alot.

Answer (score 2):

Do you still have insecure and autopublish package ?

```
  Chats.update(chat._id, chat);
```

This part seems a little weird to me.
a basic update to a collection is : Chats.update({_id : chat._id}, {$set : {message : whateverMymsgis }}); Meteor is kind of strict with the update method you will always need to pass the _id to update something.

If you don't have autopublish and insecure packages, have you made all the allow / publish / subcription part to your collections ??

Hope it will help :)

Comment: Thank you, I also took your advice but and updated the Chats.update but I may have done it wrong because I am getting a new error. Which is, update failed: Access denied. No allow validators set on restricted collection for method 'update'. I changed it to Chats.update({_id : chat._id}, {$set : {message : msgs}});

Answer (score 1):

This has happened because you removed `insecure` package and have not specified any `allow/deny` for your `chat` collection and also your meteor method has been written on the `client` side.

The quick and proper solution would be moving your meteor method to the `server side`.

Comment: Thank you, I took your advice and moved the method to the server side and I added a allow. I no longer get the error when clicking on a user but I receive a new error when I attempt to send a message. Which is, update failed: Access denied. No allow validators set on restricted collection for method 'update'.

Comment: Chats.allow({
    insert: function(userId, doc) {
      // only allow posting if you are logged in
      return !! userId;
    }
  });

Comment: I also changed the Chats.update under my events.  Chats.update({_id : chat._id}, {$set : {message : msgs}});

Comment: just like `insert` you need to have `allow/deny` rules for your `update` also, otherwise it'll throw error. Or you can always shift your `update code` into a separate `server side` method and call that method in the client.

Comment: Thanks Faysal, I was able to make these changes prior to reading your comment and I no longer am getting an error. However, I have another issue. Once I click sent on my input form, it is not appearing at all. Not sure why, but ill keep looking into it. If you have any ideas, that would be very helpful.

Comment: please post a separate question and let me know.

Comment: and if the earlier problem was solved using my solution please mark this as answer.